# Efeito ao passar o mouse

Tags: css, html5, css3

Eu gostaria de saber como fazer isso com as imagens no CSS. Desde já, agradeço!
Link do site http://demo.athemes.com/sydney/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Utilizando o `:hover`, `transform` e um `transition` da pra conseguir um efeito bem parecido:

```css
.fundo{
background:#e3e3e3;
width:200px;
height:300px;
padding:5px;
background-image:url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/f2/40/24/f24024aec1447cdb0418bbc8d349ec6c.jpg);
background-position:center;
background-size:cover;
}

.frente{
  opacity:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#d65050;
  color:#fff;
  transition: all .2s;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  font-family:verdana;

}

.frente:hover{
  opacity:1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="fundo">
  <div class="frente">
    <h2>Nome</h2>
    <p>Descrição</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a propriedade `position` para obter esse efeito, segue um exemplo:

```css
.team {
  position: relative;
}

.team__img { 
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.team__detail {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.team:hover .team__detail { visibility: visible; }
```

```html
<div class="team">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/49/91/58/499158d23cd845e7a95d3fe46f173f28--rick-y-morty-fondos-rick-and-morty.jpg" alt="" class="team__img">
  <div class="team__detail">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Ana, tudo bem?

Sim, tudo é possível fazer com CSS3.

Acho que um site muito bacana para você tirar suas idéias é o Codepen.
Vou mandar um link de efeitos de card e o link do próprio site.
Da uma olhada, você vai achar muitos conteúdos bacanas lá.

https://codepen.io/itbruno/pen/gvEtl

https://codepen.io

Espero ter ajudado.

Abs

Comment: Uauuu! Amei o site, muito obrigada. 
Ajudou muito! Abs

Comment: Sim, ele é muito bom.

Answer (score -1):

Olá para fazer isso é só você criar este código e ir acertando o valor do `margin-left` e `margin-right`. Você vai testando até que o quadrado vermelho desejado fique em cima da sua foto ok?

SUA FOTO AQUI

```
<img src='suaimagem.html' style='width:300px; height:300px; '/>

<div class='quadrovermelho' style='position:absolute; width:300px; height:300px; background-color:red; opacity:0.6; margin-left:vcvaiajustando; margin-top:vcvaiajustando; '></div>
```

Comment: Veja o exemplo que criei, daquela forma você não precisa ficar controlando a posição utilizando `margin`.